# Ordering a comboBox by the int value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

having a lot of problems ordering my combobox by value any help is greatly appreacitated

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //text to hold the conbo box, text is grabed from the AS2W14data.csv file from c:\temp\...
        String variable;
        variable = "";
        //filll in the combo box , create a reader
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"c:\temp\AS2W14data.csv");
        //use a while loop to read the entire file line by line, using the current line to populate the comboBox
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            variable = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] currentLineIndex = variable.Split(',');
            //customer ID is indexed at the string array postion 1
            //Customer name is indexed at the string array position 0
            cboCustomer.Items.Add(currentLineIndex[1].Trim() + " " + currentLineIndex[0].Trim());
        }
        //close the file to prevent errors...
        sr.Close();
    }
```

this is my code so far and i cant seem to find a way to order it.. help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest ordering them before adding them to the combo. Also here's a little shortcut for reading a text file. First, you want to read lines by streaming them (`ReadLines()` returns `IEnumerable<string>`) into a projection (`Select()`) where you create an anonymous object with two properties - `Id` and `Name`. At the end, you order a collection of these anonymous objects by the `Id`.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\AS2W14data.csv")
                .Select(l => new 
                { 
                    Id = int.Parse(l.Split(',')[1].Trim()), 
                    Name = l.Split(',')[0].Trim() 
                }).OrderBy(i => i.Id);

foreach (var l in lines)
    cboCustomer.Items.Add(l.Id + " " + l.Name);
```

Comment: hey that really helped big time, any chance you would know how to order them by the value of the entire number 1<19?

Comment: I edited my post. Just make that Id of `int` type. Be sure, that there are really numbers, otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: Thanks alot man, that was exactly what i was looking for,,would you mind explaining how it grab the line, i understand the splitting, but the    ->     .select(l => new {}  is currently ruffling my brain, haha

Comment: I expanded my answer with an explanation on what's going on there. You will have to read more about those topic to really unstertand them, though.

Comment: @The---Doctor If you find my answer helpful, you should mark it as accepted so that other users known that it solves the problem.

Comment: fairly new to stack site, but u got it

Answer (score 0):

try this code hope it will work alternatively you can use `Sorted` Property of `ComboBox`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //text to hold the conbo box, text is grabed from the AS2W14data.csv file from c:\temp\...
    String variable;
    variable = "";
    ArrayList Indexs = new ArrayList();
    //filll in the combo box , create a reader
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"c:\temp\AS2W14data.csv");
    //use a while loop to read the entire file line by line, using the current line to populate the comboBox
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        variable = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] currentLineIndex = variable.Split(',');
        //customer ID is indexed at the string array postion 1
        //Customer name is indexed at the string array position 0
        Indexs.Add(new AddIndexValues(currentLineIndex[1].Trim() + " " + currentLineIndex[0].Trim());
    }
    //close the file to prevent errors...
    cboCustomer.DataSource = DataBaseBuilds.Indexs;
    sr.Close();
}

public class AddIndexValues
{
   private int i_index;
   public AddIndexValues(int Index)
   {
      i_index = Index;
   }
   public int Index
   {
      get { return i_index; }
   }
}
```